# Ubuntu 17.10 not recognizing Broadcom wireless adapter BCM 4360 [14e4:43a0]

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, 17.10

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and my ASUS wireless adapter is not found.

The result of `lspci -v`:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
```

I do not have an internet connection on the system. I have never had an issue with this system and the wireless adapter on previous versions of ubuntu (as far back as 16.04). Have the necessary drivers been removed from the linux kernel? How do I get the drivers installed without an internet connection?

Comment: The link above worked! Thanks! Apologies for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to `-generic` kernel, then running the following when booted fixed it for me:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`